# How to do this float/align without an extra div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to get a navigation bar that consists of a nav with an unordered list in it to align to the right side of the page's width. The nav itself should span the entire width (it's a black bar across the entire page) but the links itself should be aligned to the right of the contents width, like so:

```
|                                        home | about | etc.               |
|                                                                          |
|            This is content with a fixed with in the center               |
|            of the page.                                                  |
```

The HTML I have:

```
<nav>
 <ul id="navlist">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">etc,</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  display:block;
  background:#000;
 }

  nav ul {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 777px;
  }
   nav ul li {
    float:left;

   }
```

But of course that's on the left side of the page, and I can't seem to get it to the right without adding an extra div element... The only option is to float the `<li>`'s right, but that would mean my navigation is in reverse order and I really don't want that... It's an auto generated list of pages in a wordpress install, so I could then order the pages reversely in the admin panel but having to alter backend stuff is not really a good way to handle a design.

Anyone?

Comment: ah, thanks Kyle. Guess something went wrong :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav {
  display:block;
  background:#000;
  text-align:right;      
 }

  nav ul {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 777px;
  }
   nav ul li {
    display: inline;

   }
```

Comment: You didn't need the float. I posted the whole thing.

Comment: Hmm, nice. Guess I'll have to find a way to style the li elements now, but I think inline-block will do for most browsers. Thanks!

Comment: not sure if you should use it. `display:inline` breaks only the width/heoght setting. You can change width and height of elements with `padding` and `line-height`

Comment: I know, I'll find a way. Thanks again!